# Sharepoint 2010 with excel 2010 error

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010

This is the first question for me on this site, and I wish my issue will be solved by you :)

I am creating a small utility which reads from a SharePoint List and from Excel sheet in order to map fields for doing some kind of migrating data from excel to SP list, 
The utility is first populating SP lists from SharePoint depending on the URL provided, then loads columns for the selected List in a Datagrid, then it reads excel sheet and populates all columns in another datagrid:

- the first problem I faced was that I was not able to add **Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll**  this   was solved by changing .Net Framework from **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile** to **.NET Framework 3.5** since I got the below error:

***Error    1   The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)***

So Far SharePoint is working fine, Now when attempting to read from Excel sheet, I get error the below Error:

I have used OLEDB and ODBC connections as below, but none worked under x64:

string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + this.textBox3.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";

***The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.***

string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + this.textBox3.Text + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

***The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.***

string sConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ="+ this.textBox3.Text +"";
***ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified***

After some search, I read that we need to build this application under 86x to solve excels issue, I did that and the problem was solved for excel, but now SharePoint is not working and giving the error message below:

***The Web application at
 `http://localhost/ITO` could not be
 found. Verify that you have typed the
 URL correctly. If the URL should be
 serving existing content, the system
 administrator may need to add a new
 request URL mapping to the intended
 application.***

As you see, Excel Columns are populated here, but SharePoint is giving error!!
Any Idea in how to let both of them work in the same application??

Answer (score 1):

1. Microsoft.SharePoint.dll is **only** for Applications running on the SharePoint server, not for Apps running on a client machine. For Client Applications, use the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sp2010devtrainingcourse_clientobjectmodel_unit) or the Web Services.
2. When using the SharePoint DLLs, the Application must be x64, not x86 (the default for Console Apps) or AnyCPU - SharePoint 2010 is 64-Bit *only*. (The above Client OM works on 32-Bit of course)
3. When using the SharePoint DLLs, use .net 3.5, but you already figured that out :)
4. Technically, using Microsoft.SharePoint.dll outside of SharePoint (either the website or a timer job) isn't supported either - it works in most cases though.

Comment: I am running it on the SharePoint Server not the client, its a development environment, both functionality areworking fine but not together, because i need to change the Build platform between x64 and x86, is there any way to make excel connection to work under x64 since sharepoint is running on the same??

Comment: As below, Office 64 bit is available. And probably what you need to upgrade to.

Comment: When i create a connection using VS 2010 Data Connection and choose ODBC Data connection i am able to connect to the Excel and read the values! why its not working using code?

Comment: Visual studio is a 32 bit app. I don't know anything about 64 bit office data connectivity, sorry. Worst case scenario: write 2 apps, one for excel and one for sharepoint and use temp files or named pipes to communicate, or even wcf.

Comment: I have installed MS office for 64 bits and that solved my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by saying that Sharepoint 2010 need to be run in 64bit and on .net 3.5. Get that sorted, and your sharepoint will work. You might then have to install 64bit version of excel to get it working on the same platform.

WHat you have now is a hotch potch of 3.5 and 4.0, and 64 bit and 32 bit parts, which will never work together.

Comment: Hi Schroedingers Cat, SharePoint is running fine when using .NET Framework 3.5 and x64, but what to do to make Excel run on the same? Is there and Office connection which runs under x64?

Comment: You can get office for 64 bit, which you will have to use, I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed MS office for 64 bits and that solved my issue :)